# Intel XDK Geolocation won't find Lat/Long if location services off

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, geolocation, intel-xdk

I am using the Intel XDK to develop an app where i am specifically testing with android (Nexus 6P).

I have added the Cordova Geolocation plugin as well as Google Location Services for Cordova and have tested with my location services switched on and it correctly gets the position for both plugins.

However, when i switch off location services, nothing appears at all.

Here is the code i am currently using to get the location:

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    var Geo={};
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log('Started location');
        console.log(cordova.plugins.locationServices.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error));
        //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, {enableHighAccuracy:true, maximumAge:Infinity, timeout:100000});
    }

    //Get the latitude and the longitude;
    function success(position) {
        console.log('SUCCESS location');
        Geo.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        Geo.lng = position.coords.longitude;
        populateHeader(Geo.lat, Geo.lng);
    }

    function error(){
        console.log("Geocoder failed");
    }

    function populateHeader(lat, lng){
        $('#Lat').attr('data-lat', lat);
        $('#Long').attr('data-long',lng);
    }
}
```

What i'm after, is either a way of asking the user to switch on location data, or even better would be to get the location of the user WITHOUT the location services being required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "when I switch off location services" I assume you mean that you have gone into the Android settings and disabled the "Location History" or the turned off sharing "Location" on the device. In this case, you won't get any data because the user has elected not to share that information. See the warnings in the README for both plugins, this is considered very sensitive data and, therefore, Android has given users the ability to control sharing this information.

I don't know if there is an API that would explicitly tell you whether or not that data has been disabled by the user. Regardless, you should probably report that you cannot get the data you need, which could be due to a variety of reasons:

- the sharing of location data has been disabled by the user
- the device is unable to retrieve a current position at this time
- the current "location mode" is not allowing for retrieval of a position

And then follow that up with some advice on what to change or fix in order to allow that data to be collected and used. Of course, if the user is not interested in ever sharing that information with your app you'll have to gracefully comply.

---

*EDIT 23 Feb 2017: See comment below for reference to some plugins that can help identify if location services are available.*

Comment: Okay cool. So is there a way I can get the app to open location data settings to enable like other apps do with the XDK?

Comment: That would either require a Cordova plugin, if it's not already provided in the ones you're using (I think both only provide the geo APIs) or some clever use of intents (for which there are plugins). Search for a Cordova or PhoneGap plugin that does that or check to see how it is done in native Java, if it can be done with an intent (I'm not sure how it's done). If it must be done with a plugin, you could potentially modify one of those geo plugins to add an additional API call to make that happen -- one of the beauties of those plugins being open source. :)

Comment: Awesome. I did have a good old look but couldn't quite find what I was looking for in that respect but I shall dig deeper and report back in the next few hours. Thank you very much!

Comment: There is a plugin that can be used to assist in detecting whether or not location services are available and can even assist in directing the user to the relevant settings on the device. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic if you are building with the Android 6+ tools and use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic.api-22 if you are building with a system that uses older build tools.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the "options" to determine the time of the " timeout" so return the error ! =)

```
function cbSucessGeo(p)
{
    console.log(p); //current GPS coordinates
}

function cbFailGeo(e)
{
    switch(e.code)
    {
        case 1:
            alert("PERMISSION DENIED");
            break;
        case 2:
            alert("POSITION_UNAVAILABLE");
            break;
        case 3:
            alert("TIMEOUT");
            break;
        default:
            alert("UNKNOWN ERROR");
            break;
    }
}

var options = { timeout: 5000, maximumAge: 0, enableHighAccuracy: true };

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(cbSucessGeo, cbFailGeo, options);
```

If GPS is turned off the onError callback is invoked after timeout interval (if specified). If timeout parameter is not specified then no callback is called.

Peace! =)